# Can we send Files via message bus to another agent

Tags: volttron

I am trying to send a file from a Volttron Agent to an Agent running outside volttron(StandAlone).
So far I am able to connect the Volttron Agent to Standalone agent.

but Is it possible to send a file. ( A simulation model file) via the message bus or thru any other mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a file through the message bus using a base64 encoded string.  This is not the most efficient way, but it is the easiest.  You should be able to do this by exposing an rpc method or subscribing to a known topic.

The other way is to use the channel subsystem (only available via zmq).  This provides low level access to a zmq socket.  You can send bytes across the wire between agents.

Comment: I will try with base64, this seems the simplest. 
Thanks

Not sure of the "channel subsystem" way. Although I am using ZMQ bus but haven't heard or gone thru an example of this before.